# get the generic class type at runtime when autowiring

Tags: java, spring, generics

I'm having a base class which operates on third party library and specific repo class. I'm using the base class as composition. I'm getting error while autowiring the base class while getting generic type as run time.

```
@Repository
public interface BaseRepo<T, K> { 
  public void save(T obj);
  public T get(K id);

}


@Repository
public class BaseRepoImpl<T, K> implements BaseRepo<T, K>{ 

  private Class<T> classType;

  public BaseRepoImpl(){
    Type[] types = ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
   this.classType = types[0];
  }
  
  public void save(T obj){
    somethirdParty.save(obj);
  }

  public T get(K id){
     return somethirdParty.get(classType, id);
   }
}

@Repository
public interface MyRepo { 
  public void save(MyObject obj);
  public T get(String id);

}

@Repository
public class MyRepoImpl implements MyRepo{ 
  
   private BaseRepo<MyClass, String> baseRepo;

   public void save(T obj){
     baseRepo.save()
   }

  public T get(String id){
    return baseRepo.get(id);
  }
}
```

Getting below error while tomcat startup -

```
main ContextLoader Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseRepoImpl' defined in file [...BaseRepoImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.intuit.qbo.data.dynamodb.DynamoDBRepositoryImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
```

Comment: You did it in wrong way, those generic repository can not be marked as component. You can read more about custom repository from Spring doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: I'm not using spring data repository